# What is the general techique to solve the following type of recursive integrals?

Tags: integration, recursive-algorithms, reduction-formula

Consider the recursive definition of the following function:

\begin{equation}
\omega(t, a) = 1 + \frac{1}{t} \cdot \biggl( \int_{0}^{t-a}\! \omega(t-x, a) \, dx \biggr)
\end{equation}

We can assume that $t \geq a$.

The base branch is not given, but we can infer from the recursive branch. When $t = a$, $\omega (t, a) = \omega(a, a) = 1$.

It would be best to write the analytic expression for $\omega(t, a)$. However, if there is no way to accurately write the analytic expression of $\omega(t, a)$, Is there any approximation method to approaching its value in any precision?

Comment: Have you tried fixed point theory? Are there any additional properties on $\omega$, for instance continuity, boundedness, integrability on the entire domain? Where does $t$ come frome? Is it the entire half-axis $t\in[a,\infty)$?

Comment: The integral is a lot easier to work with as $\int_a^t\omega(u,a)du$.